# I fixed the last problem but now i've got this.File "main.py", line 103, in main bullet = pygame.Rect ( TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Tags: pygame

This is the error I'm getting but I don't see a problem on line 103 with anything
If there really is a problem PLs let me know.For some reason It's not letting me submit this complaint without having more text so thats what Im trying to do.

```
  File "main.py", line 103, in main
    bullet = pygame.Rect(
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

```

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cosmic Shooters")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2-5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)
    
BULLET_VEL = 8
MAX_BULLETS = 3


FPS = 60
VEL = 5
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40
BULLET_VEL = 8
MAX_BULLETS = 3

YELLOW_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
RED_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2




YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)


RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 270)

def draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)

    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)   
    
    pygame.display.update()

def yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VEL > 0: # left
            yellow.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + VEL + yellow.width < BORDER.x : # right
            yellow.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - VEL > 0: # up
            yellow.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + VEL + yellow.height < HEIGHT - 15 : # down
            yellow.y += VEL

def red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x - VEL > BORDER.x + BORDER.width: # left
            red.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x + VEL + red.width < BORDER.x: # right
            red.x += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and  red.y - VEL > 0 : # up
            red.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and red.y + VEL + red.height < HEIGHT - 15 : # down
            red.y += VEL


def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        bullet.x += BULLET_VEL
        if red.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(RED_HIT))
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        bullet.x -= BULLET_VEL
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOW_HIT))
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)

def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)

    red_bullets = []
    yellow_bullets = []
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL and len(yellow_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y, yellow.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    yellow_bullets.append(bullet)

                
                if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL and len(red_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        red.x, red.y + red.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    red_bullets.append(bullet)
                    
                

        print(red_bullets, yellow_bullets)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
        yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow)
        red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red)


        handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red)    

        
        draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets)


        

    pygame.quit()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Again it's not letting me go without more details but I really don't know could possibly be the issue.

Comment: That's an indentation error. The error line isn't under the `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` guard.

Comment: Make sure the event is a keydown event before accessing it's key attribute, as @tdelaney said

Comment: @tdelaney  thank you so much not sure how i missed that.

Comment: Got another problem @tdelaney think you can help? thx

Answer (score 1):

Not all `pygame.event`s are key presses, you should check what type of event it is before accessing the `key` attribute.